# Trigger "don't do this" message if question starts/ends with filler

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

So you're not supposed to start questions with "Hello guys" or end them with a signature, right? Well, here's an idea: Detect common cases of this and warn the user that this is unwanted cruft.

So, if your question starts with:

- hello
- hi
- hey
- etc.

...or ends with:

- `username` (likely an indicator of trying to manually sign)
- thanks in advance ([this is discouraged, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:0%20%22thanks%20in%20advance%22))

...then a box pops up that says:

> Your question starts with "hello". This is considered unnecessary; please remove it.

...or:

> Your question ends with your username. You do not need to "sign" your questions; please remove it.

...and so on. It shouldn't be blocking, just informational.

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't usually vote to close as dupe because of an answer, but since this is an Official Canonical Jeff Answer, I guess it qualifies for an exception. Nice, @JoshCaswell.

Comment: @Popular: The Jefficial answer still counts for something, huh? I figured random would just start erasing history around the beginning of the month. Eventually there'd be a Meta question: "Why is there no user #1?"

Comment: "Your question ends with your username." Considering some people here have really odd usernames, filtering on that is going to be a challenge.

Comment: I wonder if "so" could be likewise auto-deleted.  E.g. "So you're not supposed to start questions..." -> "You're not supposed to start questions..."

Answer (score 5):

Greetings like this are actually [already filtered out automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989). There is a regex which checks for the presence of things like that at the beginning of a post and just strips them out silently when it's posted. It does not for signature sorts of things at the end though:

> The thanks parts at the end of posts are much more difficult / risky to detect, so we are not touching those for now.

Comment: The regex is posted at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989

Comment: Thanks @KevinVermeer, I was looking for that post but couldn't find it. I edited that into the answer.